# Force .o files in .a to use some symbols from within that .a

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, elf

Let's say I have `foo.a` with

```
a.o
  T aaa
  U bbb

b.o
  T bbb
```

How can I either modify `foo.a` or create a relocatable `foo.o` such that when it is linked in another project, `a.o:bbb` uses `b.o:bbb` instead of a `bbb` that might be defined elsewhere? Note that I can't use `--whole-archive` because `main` is defined in one the .o in `foo.a`. Also note that I can know the symbols to keep global (eg `aaa`) or to use local (eg `bbb`) if that helps.

I tried to create a relocatable object with a version script exporting only `aaa` in the hope `bbb` would be linked local implicitly. Unfortunately, the resulting .o contains no symbols:

```
$ cat version.script
{ global: aaa; local: *; };
$ ld -relocatable --version-script version.script foo.a -o foo.o
$ nm foo.o
nm: foo.o: no symbols
```

This might not even be the right approach so I'm open to suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I either modify foo.a or create a relocatable foo.o such that

```
ld -r --whole-archive foo.a -o foo1.o &&
objcopy -w -L.* -Gaaa foo1.o foo.o &&
rm foo1.o

nm foo.o
0000000000000000 T aaa
0000000000000010 t bbb
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

> I tried to create a relocatable object with a version script

Linker version scripts don't work for relocatable objects, they can only control symbols in the *dynamic* symbol table which relocatable objects lack.

> Note that I can't use --whole-archive because main is defined in one the .o in foo.a

That's trivial to fix:

```
ld -r -u aaa foo.a -o foo1.o
```

This will cause *only* the object which *defines* `aaa` (`a.o` here) and any other objects defining symbols referenced by `a.o` to be pulled in.

If you need to export multiple symbols (e.g. `aaab`, `aaac`, etc.) you'll need to adjust both the `ld` and the `objcopy` commands to list them.

Comment: The reason I use a version script is because some .o in `foo.a` defines `main`, among other functions that might be duplicated, so I can't use `--whole-archive`.

Comment: @cr3 The same solution can trivially be adapted to your situation, and the version script _still_ has nothing to do with this. This answer gives you complete solution to the question you asked. You should accept it, and ask a new question if this wasn't your actual problem.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, your answer was already known in the question where it says "Note that I can't use --whole-archive..." I will gladly accept your answer if you could kindly provide the "trivial adaptation", even just as a comment if there's enough space. Thank you!